# How to make dexterity modifications available to other clients?

Tags: plone, dexterity

The modified `model_source` of a dexterity type is not available for other clients until the other client restarts.

Invalidating or clearing the `SCHEMA_CACHE` is not a working solution: every client seems to have its own `SCHEMA_CACHE` which afik cannot be cleared or invalidated from another client.

Is there any solution to solve this problem?

The scenario presented here uses ipython as second client. The same can be reproduced through the web by starting two clients: (1) create a dexterity type in client1, and (2) edit the XML Field Model in client2.

I'd like to put this as an issue on https://github.com/plone/plone.dexterity but as for today issues seem not to be available in the `plone.dexterity` github project

```py
utils.sync()
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName
from plone.dexterity.fti import DexterityFTI
id = 'mydexteritytype'
plone_site = app.Plone
tool_portal_types = getToolByName(plone_site, 'portal_types')
if tool_portal_types.hasObject(id): tool_portal_types.manage_delObjects(id)
utils.commit()
utils.sync()
fti = DexterityFTI(id)
fti.id = id
data = {}
data['title'] = id
data['i18n_domain'] = 'plone'
data['behaviors'] = "\n".join([
            'plone.app.dexterity.behaviors.metadata.IDublinCore',
            'plone.app.content.interfaces.INameFromTitle',
            ])
data['model_source'] = '''
<model xmlns:security="http://namespaces.plone.org/supermodel/security"
       xmlns:marshal="http://namespaces.plone.org/supermodel/marshal"
       xmlns:form="http://namespaces.plone.org/supermodel/form"
       xmlns="http://namespaces.plone.org/supermodel/schema">
    <schema>
        <field name="original" type="zope.schema.TextLine">
            <default>original</default>
            <description/>
            <title>original</title>
        </field>
    </schema>
</model>'''
data['klass'] = 'plone.dexterity.content.Container'
data['filter_content_types'] = True
data['icon_expr'] = 'string:${portal_url}/document_icon.png'
fti.manage_changeProperties(**data)
tool_portal_types._setObject(fti.id, fti)
utils.commit()
```

After running the code above, the new created `mydexteritytype` is available for all other clients.

The modifications produced by the following code will be only available in the client running the code. All other clients are not aware of the changes.

```py
utils.sync()
from plone.dexterity.interfaces import IDexterityFTI
from zope.component import getUtility
fti = getUtility(IDexterityFTI, name=id)
model_source = '''
<model xmlns:security="http://namespaces.plone.org/supermodel/security"
       xmlns:marshal="http://namespaces.plone.org/supermodel/marshal"
       xmlns:form="http://namespaces.plone.org/supermodel/form"
       xmlns="http://namespaces.plone.org/supermodel/schema">
    <schema>
        <field name="modified" type="zope.schema.TextLine">
            <default>modified</default>
            <description/>
            <title>modified</title>
        </field>
    </schema>
</model>'''
fti.manage_changeProperties(model_source=model_source)
from plone.dexterity.schema import SCHEMA_CACHE
SCHEMA_CACHE.invalidate(fti)
SCHEMA_CACHE.clear()
utils.commit()
```

Comment: Submit the issue to https://dev.plone.org/newticket. The only reason to post an issue for a module on github is if you're involved enough in development to know the right issue tracker.

Comment: I've created the issue https://dev.plone.org/ticket/14121. Nevertheless I left this question open here in case someone comes up with a workaround. This issue is highly critical for our customer since they run a load-balanced Plone. It could be a showstopper for migrating to Plone-5/Dexterity and consequently for Plone.

Comment: A change was made over a year ago to try to support this use case -- https://github.com/plone/plone.dexterity/commit/7563951b000b50f4410f6a060d3d3c25755c4b63. What version of plone.dexterity are you using?

Comment: Plone-4.3.2 tested with default versions and with [versions] plone.dexterity=2.2.1. Same behavior. I was not yet able to test it under Plone-4.3.3 due to bug https://dev.plone.org/ticket/14055

Comment: default version (in Plone-4.3.2) is plone.dexterity=2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

This pull-request is supposed to fix this issue:

- https://github.com/plone/plone.dexterity/pull/137